# Typescript export module explicitly creates new namespace?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, typescript

I just noticed this behaviour and can't fully wrap my head around it.

So I have two typescript files File1.ts File2.ts

File1.ts :

```
module myNamespace {
    export class myClass1 {
         someMethod(myClass2) // use this class
    }
}
```

File2.ts:

```
module myNamespace {
    export class myClass2 {
    }
}
```

This works and makes sense since both classes end up in the same namespace after the compilation.

However, when I change File2.ts into this

```
export module myNamespace {
    export class myClass2 {

    }
}
```

When I add the export keyword in front of the module keyword the typescript compiler complains that it can no longer find myClass2 in File1.ts

Why is that? Is it because export explicitly sets up a new namespace regardless if it already exists? The created javascript is nearly identical for File2.ts except for

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) { .. }
```

Does this define call crate a new closure I have to dig into?

Sorry if this is a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a compiler requirement. On the playground I get this error with your code:

[image]

Everything works fine, however, if I change the code to this:

[image]

or this..

[image]

In both cases, the output code is the same.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. If you export one, the compiler wants you to export all of the namespaces

Comment: -1 for avoiding the underlying problem (whether these declarations are in the same file is extremely relevant) and using screenshots when code samples would have been fine

Comment: Did not realize that about the files, my bad. I'm learning. But come off about the screenshots, dude. :) I think the first screenshot does a good job of explaining what I was seeing and how I came to my conclusion.